# Как подружить viewBinding и вложенный макет?

Tags: kotlin, android-view-binding

Всем привет! Есть проект на основе шаблона Basic Activity. В макете activity_main.xml есть вложенный макет `<include layout="@layout/content_main" />` Во вложенном макете я сделал единственное представление- recyclerView. Теперь я хочу задать параметры для этого recyclerView с помощью viewBinding(через синтетику или findView... понятно как). Если бы был отдельный класс фрагмента, который бы добавлялся через fragment manager в контейнер в main activity, то все было бы понятно. Но как быть в ситуации с вложенным макетом? Думал в main activity в onCreate сделать что-то типа:

```
binding = ContentMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
binding.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```

но это не работает

Answer (score 2):

в русскоязычной части stackoverflow ответа не нашлось, зато нашел в англоязычной. нужно для вложенного макета назначить id:

```
<include android:id="@+id/idForInclude"
        layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

а потом биндить через класс от main activity:

```
binding2 = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
binding2.idForInclude.recyclerView.layoutManager = layoutManager
```